# Architecture recommendation - Azure Webjob

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-web-app-service

I have a webjob that subscribes to an Azure service Bus topic. The webjob automates a very important business process. For the Service bus, it is Premium SKU and have Geo-Recovery configured. My question is about the best practice to setup High Availability for my webjob (to ensure that the process runs always). I already have the App Service Plan deployed in two regions, and the webjob is installed in both the regions. However, I would like my webjob in the secondary region to run only if the primary region is down - maybe temporarily due to an outage. How can this be implemented? If I run both the webjob in parallel, that will create some serious duplication issues. Is there any architectural pattern I can refer to, or use any features within App Service or Azure to implement this?

Comment: if those sites are independent and so the webjobs in them will be independent of each other. If you want to make them a singleton you'll have to add some custom logic. With SingletonAttribute you could serialize -that all executions of the function at that region scope to be serialized.

Comment: @AjayKumar-MSFT Do you have a link or an article that I can follow to get more details on SingleTon Attribute at a region level?

Comment: Kindly take a look at the samples here https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#scope-values and see if that helps your requirement.

Comment: How would you detect the primary region is down? Would your ops team make the decision to failover to secondary? Or do you have an automated process?

Comment: In AppService, it is detected looking at the HTTP status code received from a health check URL. If there is a 500 or timeout after 3 retries, then it's a call for failover

Comment: @AjayKumar-MSFT The Singleton attribute will work only if the webjob is deployed in a Single region and when you have multiple instances within the region. Whta is I have the same webjob running in a different region for Active-Active HA implementation?

Comment: @Thomas Can I ask if you managed to find a good solution to this? I have the same problem, and would be very helpful if you found something!

Answer (score 0):

With ServiceBus, when you can pick up a message, it is locked so shouldn't be picked up by another process unless the lock time expires or you issue a compled message back to service bus. In your case, if you are using Peek Lock, you can use it to prevent the same message being picked up by different instances. [See docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-transfers-locks-settlement)

You can also make use of [sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions) which is available in the premium instance of ServiceBus. In this way, you can group messages to a session and each service instance handles their own session unless the other instance is not available.

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking for more on the HA for webjobs.

Answer (score 0):

Since WebJob is associated with App service , so really depends how you have configured this. You already mentioned that WebJobs are in 2 regions which mean you have app services running in 2 regions. (make sure you have multiple instance running in each region and different Availability zones).

Now it comes down what configuration you have regarding standby region. Is it Active/passive with hot Standby, Active/passive with cold Standby or is it active/Active. If your secondary region is Active where you have atleast one instance running then your webjob is actually processing the message.

I would recommend read through these patterns and understand.

[Standby Regions Configuration](https://mitchelsellers.com/blogs/2018/09/05/geo-redundant-application-deployment-in-azure) , [Multi Region Config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/app-service-web-app/multi-region)

Regarding Service bus, When you are processing the message with Peek-Lock it means the message is not visible in the queue so no other instance would pick up. If your webjob is not able to process in time or failed to do or crash , the message become visible in the queue again and any other instance can pick it up so no two instances can pick same message.

**Better Approach**

I would recommend using Azure functions to process queue message .They are serverless offering with free invocations credit a month and are naturally highly available. 
You can find more about here

[Azure Function Svc Bus Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus)